# How to give value and automatically add it (increase) to other variable while decrease the other one in list python?

Tags: python, list

So i'm new to python and have this problem with python say there are 5 input

```
Andy 500
Bobby 200
Cindy 100
Daria 400
Elise 300
```

and they give the money to each other

```
Andy gives 100 to Bobby
Bobby gives 50 to Cindy
Cindy gives 25 to Daria
Elise gives 100 to Cindy
Daria gives 75 to Andy
```

the output should look like this

```
Andy 475
Bobby 150
Cindy 225
Daria 350
Elise 200
```

this is the code what i came up so far

```
    #initMoney = [500, 200, 100, 400, 300]
initMoney = [
        {'Andy': 500}, 
        {'Bobby': 200}, 
        {'Cindy': 100}, 
        {'Daria': 400}, 
        {'Elise': 100}
    ]

loanMoney = [100, 50, 25, 75, 100]

def loanBucks(init, loan):
    return init - loan

result = list(map(loanBucks, initMoney, loanMoney))
print(result)
print(result[0])

initMoney[0] += loanMoney[3]
initMoney[2] += loanMoney[1] + loanMoney[0]
initMoney[3] += loanMoney[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to store the money of the different people.

As for representing the transactions, I would suggest a list of dictionaries.

I will not write the code for inputting the initial names and money, and for inputting the transactions as I am sure you can manage this.

Here is the code for defining the money and transactions and for processing the transactions:

```
people = {
'Andy': 500,
'Bobby': 200,
'Cindy': 100,
'Daria': 400,
'Elise': 300
}

transactions = [
 {'from': 'Andy',  'to': 'Bobby', 'amount': 100},
 {'from': 'Bobby', 'to': 'Cindy', 'amount': 50},
 {'from': 'Cindy', 'to': 'Daria', 'amount': 25},
 {'from': 'Elise', 'to': 'Cindy', 'amount': 100},
 {'from': 'Daria', 'to': 'Andy',  'amount': 75}
]

for transaction in transactions:
    people[transaction['from']] -= transaction['amount']
    people[transaction['to']]   += transaction['amount']

for person, money in people.items():
    print(person, money)
```

which gives:

```
Andy 475
Bobby 250
Cindy 225
Daria 350
Elise 200
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are solving is perfect for learning object oriented python (Implementing classes with attributes such as exchange_money()).

However to solve this in the way you are doing you can make yourself a function, it would be more elegant.

```
initMoney = {}
initMoney['Andi'] = 500
initMoney['Budi'] = 200
initMoney['Cici'] = 100
initMoney['Didi'] = 400
initMoney['Elsa'] = 100

def exchange_money(person1, person2, amount):
    """
    Takes money from person1 and gives it to person2.

    Input:
        - Name of person 1 as string
        - Name of person 2 as string
        - Numeric for amount to transfer
    """

    if initMoney[person1] - amount < 0:
        print(f"{person1} does not have that much money!")
    else:
        initMoney[person1] -= amount
        initMoney[person2] += amount

#exchange_money('Andi', 'Budi', 100)
 #exchange_money('Andi', 'Budi', 6600)
```